# BAPI_ACTTYPE_CHANGEMULTIPLE returns empty and doesn't change anything in the Database

Tags: c#, erp, sap-erp, saprfc, bapi

I need some help to get my RFC call working. I've got my connection working properly and `BAPI_ACTIVITYTYPE_GETLIST` and `BAPI_ACTIVITYTYPE_GETDETAIL` are also working. But the following piece of code is giving me an empty RETURN table. There are also no changes committed to the Database. 
I've tried everything, but I can't seem to get it working.

ActivityTypeStruct is a structure that stores all data of a single ActivityType I got from the previous `BAPI_ACTIVITYTYPE_GETDETAIL`.

```
public void Change(ActivityTypeStruct currentActivityType)
{
    IRfcFunction transaction = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT");

    IRfcFunction function = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_ACTTYPE_CHANGEMULTIPLE");
    function.SetValue("COAREA", "1000");

    IRfcTable table = function.GetTable("ACTIVITYTYPELIST");
    table.Append();
    table.SetValue("ACTTYPE", currentActivityType.actType);
    table.SetValue("DESCRIPT", "Test-Description");
    table.SetValue("VALID_FROM", currentActivityType.valid_from);
    table.SetValue("VALID_TO", currentActivityType.valid_to);

    function.Invoke(dest);
    transaction.Invoke(dest);
    var returnValue = function.GetTable("RETURN");
    var returnValue2 = transaction.GetStructure("RETURN");
}
```

`BAPI_ACTTYPE_CREATEMULTIPLE` has the same problem. A solution would probably solve both Methods.

Comment: BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT has to be called after BAPI_ACTTYPE_CHANGEMULTIPLE

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: what messages get you back in RETURN?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qTd0CLn It's an empty table. If I set an incorrect parameter I do get an error entry in the RETURN table which points out the problem.

Comment: if the table RETURN is empty, that means everythign is OK, so I dont have another idea.

Comment: you should always run BAPI locally in SAP system at first, and if it executed fine, only then to proceed to test it in C#. There can be multiple reasons why it doesn't work and some may be related to RFC. It's always better to exclude all possible as causes as possible

Answer (score 3):

There can be more than one reason for not receiving any `RETURN` entry when calling a BAPI and it often depends on the specific case. For example:

1. The function runs ok, and simply no message is triggered (in this case check whether the change has actually been done in SAP)
2. The function execution aborted or some *critical* error happened (in this case check for function exceptions, for example with a try/catch statement)
3. There is a program error for which the `RETURN` table is not filled (in this case check in [support.sap.com](https://support.sap.com) for corrections)

**About your function**

I checked in our SAP environment looking for how `BAPI_ACTTYPE_CHANGEMULTIPLE` is used.

In appears that in some cases, the BAPI returns an exception without filling `RETURN` table. I think you can try with something like

```
try{
  . . .
  function.Invoke(dest);
  transaction.Invoke(dest);
  var returnValue = function.GetTable("RETURN");
  var returnValue2 = transaction.GetStructure("RETURN");

}catch (Exception ex){
  ErrorMessage = ex.ToString()
}
```

Also: I don't know which SAP component version you're working with, but I also found an old OSS note [1888336 - BAPI_ACTTYPE_CHANGEMULTIPLE: Several errors are not issued](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1888336). Maybe it is outdated but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your write operation BAPI function modules in a stateful call sequence, otherwise the `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` will be called via a fresh RFC connection and not in the same context (LUW) as the preceding `BAPI_ACTTYPE_CHANGEMULTIPLE`. Hence, the data in the first LUW is not committed and therefore also not persisted in the database.

Try this:

```
    RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(dest);
    try
    {
        function.Invoke(dest);
        transaction.Invoke(dest);
    }
    finally
    {
        RfcSessionManager.EndContext(dest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bit confusion about the two concepts of stateful RFC and transactional RFC, so let me explain the difference.

1. Stateful RFC is needed for so called "update BAPIs", i.e. BAPIs that run in a V1 or V2 work process and make changes to the database.

   Code example is basically as given by Trixx above:

   - Start a stateful user session on the backend by RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(dest);
   - Execute the BAPI
   - Check RETURN for errors (and/or catch exceptions, if the BAPI misbehaves)
   - If everything is ok, call BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT (which executes a database COMMIT WORK on the same user session), otherwise call BAPI_TRANSACTION_ROLLBACK
   - End the stateful user session by RfcSessionManager.EndContext(dest);
     (This is necessary to avoid connection and resource leaks on the backend side as well as on .NET side!)
2. Transactional RFC is used to achieve "transactional security", i.e. execution (of possibly multiple FMs) is guaranteed to happen exactly once and in order in an atomic way ("all or nothing"). If the queued version is used, the FMs are first recorded in a queue on backend side and then executed asynchronously by a Scheduler.
   **Note that in either case the RFC layer does not return any return values!** (This is the nature of asynchronous processing.)

   See the NCo Overview document on how best to implement this. Basically you create an RfcTransaction object, add the function module(s) to it, then keep Committing the transaction periodically, until one Commit() is finally ok (usually the first attempt will be ok, but in order to guarantee "exactly once", you need to be ready to retry failed submissions). Once the Commit() ended ok, you need to delete all data for this transaction locally (to avoid "duplicates") and then call the ConfirmTransactionID() method.
   Note: the ConfirmTransactionID has nothing to do with a database COMMIT. It just tells the backend that it no longer needs to protect against duplicates and can now safely delete the TID from its status table. (So basically it's a cleanup step.)

Answer (score -3):

I finally found a way to successfully commit my changes. The following code snippet fixed it.

```
RfcTransaction transaction = new RfcTransaction();
transaction.AddFunction(function);
RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(dest);
function.Invoke(dest);
transaction.Commit(dest);
RfcSessionManager.EndContext(dest);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the solution to your question. This is a mixture of different things that do not belong together (an `RfcTransaction` for using tRfc mixed with stateful call context declarations not making sense for an RfcTransaction). Also you are calling the BAPI twice, once synchronously and once via transactional RFC (tRfc). No response parameters are returned via tRfc. You should not use `RfcTransaction` for this. Please consider to delete this wrong answer. I am pretty sure that what I have written in my answer is correct and will work.

Comment: Sorry, this is completely wrong. You mixed up two unrelated scenarios: "stateful RFC" (which is synchronous) and "transactional RFC" (which is "kind of asynchronous", or at least can be made asynchronous).

Comment: PS: Perhaps you got confused by the name of the function module BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT? This name is indeed very unfortunate... :-(  It should rather have been named something like BAPI_DB_COMMIT, because that is all it does, but it has nothing to do with transactional RFC.

Comment: I have thought a bit more about this, and why it looks to you as if your code "works". First of all: your code does not work, in the contrary: it is highly dangerous!
So why does it seem to work? Because you are executing the function module twice! Once as synchronous RFC (but without the BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT, so the changes are never committed to the DB) and afterwards a second time as transactional RFC... (which triggers an "implicit COMMIT WORK" and therefore persists the changes)
Continued in next comment.

Comment: And why is it dangerous? Because the real work is done in a transactional RFC (tRFC), and BAPIs are not suitable for tRFC:

Comment: - tRFC does not have return parameters. The FM in a tRFC is simply executed, and if it does not throw an exception, it is assumed "successful".

- BAPIs however, do not throw exceptions! If the BAPI fails, it will return an error code in the RETURN structure/table!

You see the problem now? If you use your code above in production, sooner or later the following will happen:

- end user of your app enters a wrong account number (without noticing)

- BAPI is executed as tRFC, notices the error and returns an error message in RETURN

Comment: - But tRFC ignores any return parameters, and since no exception was thrown reports this execution as "success"... :-)

And after a week or so, the end user happens to check in the backend directly and notices, that all his work of the last week has not been persisted -- despite getting success messages from your tool!

(Sure way to make end users happy... :-)  )